# Ubuntu Can't run in VM

Tags: shutdown, vmware

I was just given a work USB, they don't support MAC and sent a bootable EFI USB.

In my VMWARE windows, I can load the Ubuntu up, but as soon as I select region the error 'Running in a VM is not allowed. Shutting down.'

Added a picture also,

[image: Can't run picture]

Is there any way I can get rid of this? I don't really want to buy a windows laptop.

Comment: Are you trying to run Windows in Ubuntu or Ubuntu in WIndows? Also, which version of Ubuntu are you running/trying to run?

Comment: This sounds like a limitation of the USB stick they sent you, not of Ubuntu itself.

Comment: Im trying to run Ubuntu in windows VMware, My host is a MAC
Version 18.04.02 customised using Cubic

Codename Bionic

Comment: Boot the USB on bare-metal instead of in a VM. A stock Ubuntu LiveUSB works perfectly well in a VM, so your issue suggests that "work" has sent you something else that contains it's own built-in VM that we are not familiar with. For support with that "some thing else", you must ask whomever sent it to you.

Comment: Well I have asked, and they said you have to use a windows, not a virtual machine, I want to see if there is a workaround!

Comment: This is a HOST problem. If that is WINDOWS: using Hyper-V on Windows Host, prevents usage of VT-x / AMD-V hardware virtualization features needed by other hypervisors, like Virtual Box and VMWare, to function, especially with 64 bit Guests --> disable hyper-v.

Comment: @Rinzwind I went into VMWARE settings and turned OFF "Enable hypervisor applications in this virtual machine"

Still loads up then shuts off.

Comment: Okay??? so apparently adding "Shutdown -C" into terminal on startup cancels the shutdown...